# How do I get scope(s) when requesting token from 3rd party to do transaction list on their account?

Tags: paypal

My app allows third party users to login via PayPal and to authorise it to collect UserInfo such as name and address. I now want to get permission to do a transaction list on their account using the token they provide.

I get 401 Not Authorized using the current tokens and OAuth won't accept 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.*' as a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `api.paypal.com/v1/Payments` on behalf of third parties isn't currently supported using the REST APIs.

You can only get payment info (and transaction info) for yourself.

In order to get Transaction data on behalf of third parties, you need to use the Classic APIs, first using the Permission Services to request access, then use the Merchant API Services to get transaction data.

Edit: Jan 6th, 2016

To make requests on behalf of third-parties, you need to use the [Permissions Services API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/) to request the proper scope.

As far as I can tell (from reading the documentation), you still cannot request 3rd party payment data using the REST api. You must use the Classic Name-Value Pair/SOAP api.

Comment: Is this still the case? I have been working on a project myself this past week and with the same auth_token (with invoicing and payments scope)  I can get invoice data for customers but I cannot get payment data, it returns 401.  [This is really lame, btw - if it's true you can only get payment data for yourself.]

Comment: @NicholasC I believe so, yes. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/permissions/