# Paypal API call using Node.js returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am trying to make a test call to PayPal payment API through my Node.js application. So I followed the following steps:

1. Accessed https://developer.paypal.com/ and logged in with my PayPal live account and password.
2. After login, clicked on Dashboard -> Sandbox Accounts -> Create Account
3. Created two test accounts (one Business/ seller and the other is Personal / Buyer).
4. Used the PayPal [REST API  SDK for nodejs](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs) inside my application where I've used the exact code  provided in their example [here](https://github.com/Runnable/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/blob/master/samples/payment-with-paypal.js) except for the ClientID and Secret, which I have changed to that of the new Business/ Seller test account which I've created.

But for some reason calls to .create API endpoint return 401 - Unauthorized. So can someone please help me by telling me what I am missing / doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete response from the Paypal including the correlation id?

Comment: @Eshan When calling the API, all I got was only 401 - Unauthorized. No more details were provided by PayPal

Comment: Is this possible for you to post the sandbox email address attached to your REST Application?

Comment: @Eshan Unfortunately all emails in sandbox are my client emails, so can't post them here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21271828/492460